# SQL Server EXEC backup table with date dynamically

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am looking to backup a table and auto add the date to the end of the table name.

Here is what I have

```
declare @table char(36)= 'template_fields'

EXEC('select * into '+@table+'_'+'convert(date, getdate()) from '+@table)
```

And I want the end result to look something like

```
template_fields_09-09-2015
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just print what you do:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'tab';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * into '+@table+'_'
    +'convert(date, getdate()) from '+@table;

SELECT @sql;
```

you will get: `select * into tab_convert(date, getdate()) from tab`

You need to pass date with table name like:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1835/0)**

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'tab';
DECLARE @new_table NVARCHAR(MAX) = @table + '_' + 
                                   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), GETDATE(),105);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * into ' + @new_table + ' from '+ @table;

SELECT @sql;
/* Result select * into tab_09-09-2015 from tab */
-- EXEC(@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use EXEC to run dynamic queries, use [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead.
Second: When you want to build a SQL query with variable object names, use QUOTENAME().

```
DECLARE @table sys.sysname = 'mytable'
DECLARE @backup sys.sysname = @table + '_' + CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * INTO '
     + QUOTENAME(@backup) + ' '
     + FROM + ' '
     + QUOTENAME(@table);

EXEC sp_executesql
    @stmt = @sql
```

Please note that, the `sys.sysname` is a built in data type (essentially an alias for `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`) and SQL Server uses it internally for object names.

Note: I have no SQL Server instance accessible right now, so the above query can contain typos.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this myself. While some nice responses were added I wrote my initial query more simply to achieve this. Thank you all for the help.

```
--Declare and initiate the table
    declare @table varchar(36)= 'template_fields'
--Declare and initiate the date (YYYYMMDD) without dashes
    declare @date varchar(10) = convert(int, convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112))

--Execute the query with the variables resulting in a new table titled 'template_fields_20150909'
    EXEC('select * into '+@table+'_'+@date+' from '+@table)
```